# Textures not loading correctly?

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

Im trying to show some textures in my program, and I have this code thats used to load bitmaps into openGL textures:

```
void LoadGLTextures()
{
  // Bitmap handle and structure
  HBITMAP hBMP;
  BITMAP  BMP;

  // Generate list of textures from resources
  byte Texture[] = {IDB_FONT, IDB_SKIN, IDB_PIANO};
  glGenTextures(sizeof(Texture), &texture[0]);

   // Iterate through texture list and load bitmaps
  for (int loop=0; loop<sizeof(Texture); loop++)
  {
    hBMP = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(Texture[loop]),
                          IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_CREATEDIBSECTION);
    if (hBMP)
    {
     GetObject(hBMP,sizeof(BMP), &BMP);
     glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT,4);
     glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[loop]);
     glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
     glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);

  // Generate Mipmapped Texture (3 Bytes, Width, Height And Data From The BMP)
     gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, BMP.bmWidth, BMP.bmHeight, GL_BGR_EXT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, BMP.bmBits);
     DeleteObject(hBMP);
    }
  }
```

And while my background skin loads, and gets drawn correctly, the other (piano) texture doesn't get drawn. Im sure the drawing code is correct because when i swap which texture is used (from the piano to the background texture, in this case), the other texture gets drawn. So i think the bitmap isn't being loaded correctly. But im not sure why? Is there something glaringly obvious i have overlooked?

The bitmap is 128*256 and 24 bit colour.

If you need any of the other code please let me know.

edit - If anyone knows of any librarys that would do what I require, please let me know

Comment: Where else has this question been posted?

Comment: Codeguru.com forums - Asked pretty much the exact same question there.

Comment: Most people don't mind that too much.  Just make sure you aren't posting multiple times within the StackExchange family of sites, such as http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ or http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

It might not be working right because it's deprecated.

From http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes:

gluBuild2DMipmaps - Never use this. Use either GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP (requires GL 1.4) or the glGenerateMipmap function (requires GL 3.0).

Edit: Also, you probably need to call glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) for EACH texture unit, i.e. inside the loop where you call glBindTexture.

Comment: Well, while its probably really bad programming practise, but im using a old version of GLUT for this project. Im just making an addition to the program, and this saves me re-writing 90% of the code. 

This code _does_ work as my background texture loads correctly, so this code should work for the other texture as well. But it doesn't, which is why im kinda stumped. Its looking more likely that i'll have to re-write it, but im trying to avoid that if i can.

Thanks for your reply either way!

-M

Comment: Oh ok.  So what do you get when you draw the piano texture?  Does it just come out as black?

Comment: Yeah, its just black. I can change the colour of it with glColor() in my draw, but I've tried using simpler/smaller textures, tried different texture loading implementations, still to no avail. Its pretty much driving me insane now... But thanks for getting back to me. Its much appriciated! -M

Comment: Finally got it working using the SOIL library. - http://www.lonesock.net/soil.html - very easy to use.